# Odata $filter pass value from string array in Logic app?

Tags: azure, odata, azure-logic-apps

I have odata url and want to pass $filter values from array in logic app.

I have used `HTTP` connector to call odata api.

when in filter i passed one value it is working fine.

`"$filter": "mynumer eq '1122'`

but i want to pass all values at one in one $filter from string array

I tried like -

`"$filter": "mynumer in ('1122','1133')` but getting below error

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

```
variable('myarray') = ['1122','1133']
```

> want to pass variable('myarray') to $filter how can i achieve this?

[image]

we can able to pass like this -

> (mynumer eq '1122') or (mynumer eq '1133') but how to generate this
>   based on array variable values?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it as shown below:

```
"$filter": "FirstName eq '@{variables('MyVar')[0]}' or FirstName eq '@{variables('MyVar')[1]}'"
```

Example That I tried:

[image]

[image]

Comment: this will only work if we have 2 items what if i have 10 items?

Answer (score 0):

With [`OData 4.01`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/csprd02/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-csprd02-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_LogicalOperatorExamples), in statement is supported like this:

```
http://host/service/Products?$filter=Name in ('Milk', 'Cheese')
```

In your issue, you need use `"$filter": "mynumer in (1122,1133)"` while the number is int.

Comment: this is not working in logic app :(
giving me error after adding this query  - `<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>`

Comment: You could use [Filter array] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action) action to filter array without loop it.